# Java LeapYear Program, Don't know why the third method isn't printing?

Tags: java, methods, printing

I don't know why Its divisible is not printing. Someone, please explain. Everything is working. But not passed the third method. I don't know why.

```
package leapyear;

import java.util.Scanner;
/**
*
* @author jahkeyshagodwin
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LeapYear {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */    

public static void main(String[] args) {
 displayInstructions(); 
 getYear();
 isLeap();
}

 public static void displayInstructions() {
    System.out.println("This program asks you to enter a year as a 4 digit number. The output will indicate whether the year you entered is a leap year.");
}    

public static void getYear() {
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
int year = reader.nextInt();
} 

public int isLeap (int year) {
 if (year % 4 == 0 && year != 100); {
     System.out.println ("It's Divisible");

 }

}
```

} 
}

Comment: `year % 4` is not a valid `boolean` expression

Comment: How would I make it valid. I'm having a really hard time with this. I'm online and have no instruction. Just a book that has no examples of what I need to do this week. Thank you.

Comment: You’ll have to use some sort of logical operator, such as `==`.

Comment: like (year % 4 == 0) or can I use && because I also need it to Not be divisible by 100.

Comment: Yes use && for that then use != for not equal to

Comment: Dividing by 4 is not enough. 2100 is NOT a leap year AND dividable by 4. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year for more details. Why don't you use the Java 8 Date And tTime API for this? E.g.: Year.isLeap(aYear) (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html)

Comment: @mmirwaldt Probably because this is homework?

Answer (score 0):

You never call the method. Have the `getYear` method return the year to a variable, then call the is `isLeap` method with the year as a argument.

This is working code. I would highly recommend going back to your class and reviewing methods. You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how they work. Good Luck.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayInstructions();
    int year = getYear();
    isLeap(year);
}

public static void displayInstructions() {
    System.out.println("This program asks you to enter a year as a 4 digit number. The output will indicate whether the year you entered is a leap year.");
}

public static int getYear() {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
    int year = reader.nextInt();
    return year;
}

public static void isLeap(int year) {
    if (year % 4 == 0) {
        System.out.println("It's Divisible");

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question with the new code. And make sure you change `year % 4` to `year % 4 == 0` as @Logan said

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like now. Please edit your question.

Comment: You still aren't calling the method.

Comment: This is the error... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: leapyear.LeapYear.isLeap
 at leapyear.LeapYear.main(LeapYear.java:24)
/Users/jahkeyshagodwin/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)

Comment: You declared `isLeap()` as an int, but it doesn't return an int.

Comment: try cleaning/rebuilding your project, it might be  an IDE problem

Comment: I'm actually supposed to let it come back as true or false in the third method. and then in a fourth method let it print that its leap or not.

Comment: I'll try to rebuild arthur

Comment: @jgodwin Yes it did

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that you need to correct if you want your program to work without errors. The list of things that I see you need to change:

1. Change return value of `getYear()` from `void` to `int` (you want to return it to pass it to `isLeap()` method).
2. Assign result of `getYear()` to `int` variable (as in example it's `int` year)
3. Change `isLeap()` method to make it `static`. (you don't need instance of class containing that method that way)
4. Add `return year;` to return `int` value form `isLeap()` properly, or change return value of `isLeap()` to `void` if you don't need that year anymore.
5. I leave proper counting of leap year to you as an exercise, as for now it seems you don't fully cover the problem (as wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) stands:

*if (year is not divisible by 4) then (it is a common year)*

*else if (year is not divisible by 100) then (it is a leap year)*

*else if (year is not divisible by 400) then (it is a common year)*

*else (it is a leap year)*

6. Delete `;` after your `if` in `isLeap()` as it immediately exits your loop and **always** prints "`It's Divisible`".

---

For now, your code to make it work without proper counting a leap year, as I thing it's a great exercise for you to improve your skills and to make it work:

```
public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayInstructions();
        int year = getYear();
        isLeap(year);
    }

    public static void displayInstructions() {
        System.out.println(
                "This program asks you to enter a year as a 4 digit number. The output will indicate whether the year you entered is a leap year.");
    }

    public static int getYear() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
        int year = reader.nextInt();
        return year;
    }

    public static int isLeap(int year) {
        if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) { // here you need to make more improvemnts to make this method count leap year properly (I pasted a tip for you with italics formatting, how to count it)        
            System.out.println("It's Divisible");
        }
        return year;
    }
}
```